# Docker same images, different tags, why up command recreates the containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my project Gitlab CI pipelines, I build my docker services images and tag them with the current commit id. So when I execute `docker-compose up`, the correct image version is pulled.

Exemple :

```yaml
  nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/nginx:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: docker/nginx/
      target: nginx
```

```bash
export DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=<commit-id>
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1

docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

It works, but even if the image ID didn't change, the container is recreated. Is it possible to make docker recreate the container only if the image changed, even if the tag is different ?

docker version: 20.10.21
docker-compose version: 2.12.2

I tried to tag with "blue" and "green" manually on my computer, the image is the same, but switching from one to another keeps recreating the container.

```
docker images
registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/dev/nginx       blue                6c68cb61ac38   2 minutes ago   22.5MB
registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/dev/nginx       green               6c68cb61ac38   2 minutes ago   22.5MB
```

```
DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=blue docker-compose up -d nginx
docker ps
8816b8a3001e   registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/dev/nginx:blue

DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG=green docker-compose up -d nginx
docker ps
bfc6f1b6df41   registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/dev/nginx:green
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: As you've shown it, I wouldn't expect the container to be recreated.  Is there more to your `docker-compose.yml` than what you've shown?  (Do you `depends_on:` a container that's more obviously being recreated; do you have obsolete `links:`; ...?)

Comment: I updated the service definition. I do get some services that `depends_on` other ones, but nothing related. No `links` however. It seems that using buildkit or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that, if you change the `image:` name, Compose recreates the container – it wouldn't necessarily expect two images with different names to actually be the same image and it's not the default thing to do to check ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the image SHA instead of tag:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image

example:

`image: redis@sha256:0ed5d5928d4737458944eb604cc8509e245c3e19d02ad83935398bc4b991aac7`